# Turn off signing for Castle DynamicProxy

Tags: .net, castle, castle-dynamicproxy

I am having problems when trying to use a TypedFactoryFacility in Castle.

I'm using Castle v3.0.0 and I've created a ViewFactory, using

```
injector.AddFacility(Of TypedFactoryFacility)()
```

and:

```
container.Register(CMR.Component.For(Of IDialogViewFactory)().AsFactory())
```

This code all works fine on my machine, but when deploying it to users on VMs (who don't have local admin rights), they get the following error:

```
Unable to obtain public key for StrongNameKeyPair.
```

There's various threads around, but nothing that seems to solve my issue - how can I use DynamicProxy on machines who don't / can't have access to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\

In the [stack trace of the error](https://gist.github.com/2049289) is the line

```
Castle.DynamicProxy.ModuleScope.CreateModule(signStrongName As Boolean)
```

Which seems to suggest strong naming can be turned off somehow but I can't figure out how?

Comment: None of my assemblies are signed, so from what I've read on http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel/browse_thread/thread/44987adbc81ea79/f358c5125810404a?lnk=gst&q=strongname#f358c5125810404a it shouldn't be strong naming the dynamic assembly

Comment: Can you show the stack trace from the exception?

Comment: Also are you using the DynamicProxy library which is now in Castle.Core

Comment: @Bronumski yes I'm referencing Castle.Core.  Stack trace at https://gist.github.com/2049289

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in (upcoming) version 3.1 you can do this, right after you've created the container:

```
Container.Kernel.ProxyFactory = new DefaultProxyFactory(disableSignedModule: true);
```

In 3.0 or older you can inherit from `DefaultProxyFactory` and set the value from there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the scope of the `ProxyObjectReference` with your own `ModuleScope`?

```
var scope = new ModuleScope(
                        savePhysicalAssembly,
                        true /*disableSignedModule*/,
                        strongModulePath,
                        weakAssemblyName,
                        weakModulePath);

ProxyObjectReference.SetScope(scope);
```

Comment: I saw that suggestion on http://issues.castleproject.org/issue/DYNPROXY-146?query=%23unresolved but had no idea where to put the code?

Comment: @Rich I would put it where you wire up Windsor. Probably prior to creating the container.

Comment: No that doesn't work (before or after creating the container)

Comment: I have tried various permutations, and can't get castle to take any notice of the new scope.  I can't figure out from digging through the stack trace/reflected code where the original ModuleScope is created

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this, I just had the same exception, on a physical machine. Nothing changed overnight, but this exception started presenting in the morning.

Turned out to be low disk space issue, and the dynamic proxy assemblies couldn't be written to disk. Only realised this because I happened to notice the Windows 'low disk space' icon when it appeared briefly. :-P